# Getting Blank page While using JSP with Google App Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine

```
 package com.example.datastoreWrite;

 import java.io.IOException;

 import javax.servlet.ServletException;

 import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;

 import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

 import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

 @SuppressWarnings("serial")

 public class DataStoreWriteServlet extends HttpServlet
 {

 @Override

 protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)

 throws ServletException, IOException {

 // TODO Auto-generated method stub

 Key v1 = KeyFactory.createKey("Person", "Raghav");

 Key r1 = KeyFactory.createKey("Person", "vinay");

 DatastoreService datastore = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();

 Entity e1, e2;

 try {

 e1 = datastore.get(r1);

 e2 = datastore.get(v1);

 Long vAge = (Long) e1.getProperty("age");

 Long rAge = (Long) e2.getProperty("age");

 System.out.println("vinay age"+vAge);

 System.out.println(" age"+rAge);

 } catch (EntityNotFoundException e) {

 // Alice or Bob doesn't exist!
 }
 String message = "Simple";

 req.setAttribute("message", message); // This will be available as ${message}

 try {

 req.getRequestDispatcher("/Show.jsp").forward(req, resp);

 } catch (ServletException e) {

 // TODO Auto-generated catch block

 e.printStackTrace();
 }}}
```

HERE is MY JSP FILE

```
 <%@ page language="java"

 <html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">

 <title>Simple DataStore Display</title></head>

 <body><p>Message: ${message}</p></body>

 </html>
```

MY WEB.xml

xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"

xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"

xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee

http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" version="2.5">

```
<servlet>
<servlet-name>SimpleDataStoreApplicationTest</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>com.datasote.test.SimpleDataStoreApplicationTestServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>SimpleDataStoreApplicationTest</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/simpledatastoreapplicationtest</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<welcome-file-list>
<welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list></web-app>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect you have forgotten to close the page directive properly in the Show.jsp file.

Please use : `<%@ page language="java"%>`.

Other than the above, your code looks good to execute and if the data is not present, you will see the `Message: Simple` output in the `Show.jsp` page.

Comment: i have written tags correctly ,this is bcoz of formatting in stackoverflow template.

Comment: OK. Please show the web.xml file and how you are invoking the Servlet.

Comment: Dear Romie i have added web.xml file what i m using.

Comment: I am not sure if you are typing the code and inadvertently introducing typos here but the package+classname that you have put in the web.xml is com.example.datastore.DataStoreExampleServlet, whereas it should be com.example.datastoreWrite.DataStoreWriteServlet as per your .Java file. Pls check.

Comment: Actually i have created two servlets classes one is writing  to the appengine datastore and second one is getting from it.So what class i have written above is DataStoreWriteServlet and web.xml file is DataStoreExampleServlet .Sorry there is mistake in typos it should be com.example.datastore.DataStoreExampleServlet .But again i m getting the same error

Comment: You must declare all your Servlets in your web.xml. These Servlets are the ones that you are planning to directly link to or redirect/forward to in your code. Please define them all carefully and see if the code works. It should.

Comment: Romin could u provide me the simple code so that i can test my application.Servlet+JSP code

Comment: Now i m testing with simple one. If u have any please provide i will follow that one.

Comment: As I mentioned to you, please define all your servlets/mappings/classes correctly in the web.xml file and everything looks good.

Comment: this is my new project url ckeck it http://1.vnyraghav.appspot.com// .Its now showing error

Comment: Your link points to /datastoreexample. What is the mapping in the web.xml and please show the code of the servlet that it is pointing too. Without that it is difficult.

Comment: yeah right now only datastoreexample is showing.I m trying to find it but i m not

Comment: I had uploaded my web.xml file that is created for new SimpleDataStoreApplicationTest project. You can check by this url http://1.vnyraghav.appspot.com/